# Перевод кода с python на java или c++

Tags: python, java, c++

Вот есть такой вот код на python:

```
if not(j == 0 or j == 1 and i == 0)
```

Как он будет выглядеть на С++ или java?

Подправьте, если неправильно:

```
if ( !(j==0 || j==1) || (i==0) )
```

Comment: Хм.

          if ( j && (i || j != 1))

Правда про java утверждать не могу.

Comment: все такие молодцы, а кто-нибудь в курсе в каком порядке выполняются операции or и and и вообще всё содержимое в скобках в Питоне?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(!(j==0||j==1&&i==0))
if(j!=0&&(j!=1||i!=0))//тоже самое
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 if ( ! ((j == 0 || j == 1) && i == 0) )
```

Comment: А если внесте отрицание внутрь, то получится так:   
> if ( (j!= 0 || j!= 1) && i!= 0 )  ?

Comment: А это будет уже другое  выражение. Подучите логику

Comment: Мне кажется, что внутренние скобки не нужны - ведь лог. операторы высчитываются слева направо, но интересно могут ли влиять опции компилятора на вычисление этого выражения

Comment: И альтернативный вариант таков:

      if (i!=0 ¦¦ (j!=0 && j!=1))